# React-Bootstrap Open dropdowns menu when hovering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-bootstrap, use-state

I'm new in ReactJS and react-bootstrap. My target is open a dropdown menu when user hover (mouseover) it. I had already searched but it didn't work. 
My solution is using react hooks to store and update the current state of "hoverItem" is true or false in a array (Beacase I have 2 dropdown menu. Not only 1).

But it did not work and get an error "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"

```js
<NavDropdown onMouseEnter={handleOpen(index)} onMouseLeave={handleClose(index)} show={isOpen[index]} title={item.title} id={item.id} key={item.id}>
  {item.sub.map(element => { return (
  <NavDropdown.Item href={element.url} key={element.id} onClick={handleClose}>
    {element.item}
  </NavDropdown.Item>
  ); })}
</NavDropdown>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The update state are:

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(() => {
  //create an array with n-element and set all elements to false 
    return Array.apply(null, Array(MENU.length)).map(x => false);
  });

const handleOpen = index => {
  let temp = isOpen;
  temp[index] = true;
  setIsOpen(temp);
};

const handleClose = index => {
  let temp = isOpen;
  temp[index] = false;
  setIsOpen(temp);
};
```

The point of this issue is I dont know how to update (modify) the element state in array. Please tell me how. Thank you and sorry for my inconvenience English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a React Bootstrap NavDropdown dropdown when hovered over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61007483/making-a-react-bootstrap-navdropdown-dropdown-when-hovered-over)

Comment: No bro. Because in this section, they have only 1 dropdown menu. I have 2 dropdowns and I would like to know how to update (modify) state in array (modify element from false to true).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First error:** `onMouseEnter` and  `onMouseLeave` expected a function declaration instead of a call, because you call `handleOpen(index)`, it re-render, then re-render again, and so on ...
to fix the error:

```js
onMouseEnter={(e) => handleOpen(index)}
```

**Second error**:

```js
<NavDropdown.Item href={element.url} key={element.id} onClick={handleClose}>
```

this will call handleClose with an event, expected the `index`, to fix:

```js
 onClick={e => handleClose(index) }
```

**Third error**: your handleClose and handleOpen is updating the state with the reference to the old state, expected a new array, to fix:

```js
const handleOpen = index => {
  let temp = [...isOpen];
  temp[index] = true;
  setIsOpen(temp);
};
const handleClose = index => {
  let temp = [...isOpen];
  temp[index] = false;
  setIsOpen(temp);
};
```

Also, your `isOpen` name is ambiguous, and wrong initialization too!

```js
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(() => {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(MENU.length)).map(x => false);
});
```

should be

```js
const [status, setStatus] = useState(MENU.map(x=> false));
```

**Overall** you can write like this:

```js
const updateStatus = (value, index) => {
    const clone = [...status];
    clone[index] = value;
    setStatus(clone);
}
```

```js
<NavDropdown
    onMouseEnter={e => updateStatus(true, index)}
    onMouseLeave={e => updateStatus(false, index)}
    show={status[index]}
    title={item.title}
    id={item.id}
    key={item.id}
>
    {item.sub.map(element =>
        <NavDropdown.Item
            href={element.url}
            key={element.id}
            onClick={e => updateStatus(false, index)}
        >
            {element.item}
        </NavDropdown.Item>
    )}
</NavDropdown>
```